# Excel 2010: how to auto-refresh auto-filter based on checkbox cell link

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel2010 I have created a table of X items on rows and features of these items on Y columns. One of the features is the ***Application Area*** and I want to filter the items based on the application area type. The difficulty is the items on the table have [multiple application areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hej4.png), so I cannot use the simple filter function of excel.

I came up with an idea to have *n* check-boxes (3 for this example) and assign the output of each check-box to a different cell, e.g. A10, B10, C10. I assign relevant values to *OR* functions for each item in an extra column, e.g. column F. So, for example, when I check the application area *A* the items 1 and 3 have *TRUE* in the column *F* and I can use this column to filter the table by selecting *TRUE* in the auto filter function. See the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dgxU.png) for better understanding.

The problem is that the auto filter function does not refresh automatically after I change the status of a check box. Every time I have to *reapply* the filter in *data* ribbon. Online I found this piece of VBA code to have an auto refresh feature in the active sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 8 Then
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
End If
End Sub
```

Now, this code does work and the filter is reapplied, if I actively go to one of the cells in the *F* column and edit the cell to *TRUE* or *FALSE* manually. If I change a cell value in the *F* using the check box, the auto refresh does not work.

What is the difference between changing a cell value by typing the value and pressing *ENTER* and using a check box?

BTW, the check box is a FORM CONTROLS type, not ACTIVEX.

Any help would highly be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the following will have `Worksheet_Change` react as if you manually changed any sheet cell

assuming:

- your *Form* checkboxes names are "A", "B" and "C"
- they are assigned macros named, respectively, "A_Click", "B_Click", "C_Click"
- they are in the same sheet as the table one
- the table name is "Features"

then place the following code in any module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub A_Click()
    SetOrs
End Sub

Sub B_Click()
    SetOrs
End Sub

Sub C_Click()
    SetOrs
End Sub


Sub SetOrs()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim A As Boolean, B As Boolean, C As Boolean
    Dim appAreaStrng As String

    With ActiveSheet        
        A = .Shapes("A").ControlFormat.Value = xlOn '<~~ get CheckBox "A" value
        B = .Shapes("B").ControlFormat.Value = xlOn '<~~ get CheckBox "B" value
        C = .Shapes("C").ControlFormat.Value = xlOn '<~~ get CheckBox "C" value        

        With .ListObjects("Features")
            For i = 1 To .ListRows.Count
                appAreaStrng = .DataBodyRange.Cells(i, .ListColumns("App Area").Index) '<~~ get current row "App Area" value
                .DataBodyRange.Cells(i, .ListColumns("OR").Index) = (A And InStr(appAreaStrng, "A") > 0) Or (B And InStr(appAreaStrng, "B") > 0) Or (C And InStr(appAreaStrng, "C") > 0)
            Next i
        End With            
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @cayt: did you get through it?